# Удаление узла бинарного дерева

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть бинарное дерево, надо удалить из него элемент.
Нашел вариант - удаляем элемент а на его место ставим либо самый правый элемент его левого поддерева либо самый левый его правого поддерева.
Вопрос: как это лучше всего организовать?
Логично, что надо у замещающего элемента дописать указатели на поддеревья а у его владельца заменить указатель на него на NULL, причем у владельца удаляемого элемента заменить указатель на замещающий элемент.
Если делать все в лоб, то нужны 2 указателя на поддеревья, указатели на родителей и указатели на сами элементы.
Есть ли некий правильный способ удаления без этого гемора? Возможно более оптимизированный.

Просьба посмотреть мой код строка 164 - функция не линкуется, а вроде нормально написано.

Comment: Сделайте "в лоб". А там может увидите способы оптимизации.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В случае бинарного дерева поиска рекомендую посмотреть корректный алгоритм в *Кормене* (*"Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"* - страница 326), либо в более простом и наглядном варианте [**здесь.**](http://www.tech-faq.com/binary-tree-deleting-a-node.html)

В обоих случаях используется классическая структура данных для хранения `BST`, в которой элемент представлен кортежем `(parent, left, right, data)`.

---

В случае же обычного бинарного дерева нетривиальна только ситуация, когда у удаляемого элемента ссылки `left` и `right` - не `null`. В этой ситуации необходимо совершить обход по дереву в сторону `left` или `right`, найти первый возможный лист в дереве и **заменить удаляемый элемент на данный лист.**

Для оптимизации такой операции возможно хранить в каждом узле дерева дополнительное поле `leaf`, которое будет указывать на такой возможный лист, чтобы избежать прохода по ветке дерева в случае удаления элемента. *Хотя, как мне кажется, интерес в такой оптимизации является сугубо теоретическим.*

Comment: Шикарный алгоритм, благодарю. Я бы долго до него допирал))